# List comprehension with tkinter Scale widget data

Tags: python, tkinter, list-comprehension, tkinter-scale

I'm trying to create a python 2.7 tkinter module which uses scale widget data to influence a list comprehension which selects between animals whose probability traits are represented as a list of lists.  The module sorts and displays the three animals in ranked descending order upon clicking 'Submit' and activating the associated command.

In this example, all three animals are at 33% after clicking 'Submit' because they share the same probability data.  The animals only differ among the scale widget data in column 2 of the list of lists in that each is either aquatic, terrestrial, or both.

```
from Tkinter import BOTH, BOTTOM, Button, E, END, Entry, FLAT, Frame, Grid, HORIZONTAL, Label, LEFT, N, NO, Pack, RAISED, RIGHT, S, Scale, Text, Tk, TOP, W, YES

from operator import mul

root = Tk()
root.title('Example')

class Environment:
    def __init__(self, parent):

        # layout
        self.myParent = parent

        self.main_frame = Frame(parent, background="light blue")
        self.main_frame.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)

        self.main_left_frame = Frame(self.main_frame, background="light blue")
        self.main_left_frame.pack(side=LEFT, expand=YES, fill=BOTH)

        self.main_right_frame = Frame(self.main_frame, background="light blue")
        self.main_right_frame.pack(side=RIGHT, expand=YES, fill=BOTH)

        self.water = Scale(self.main_right_frame, from_=0.01, to=1.00, orient=HORIZONTAL, bd=0, label="Aquatic",
        background="white", troughcolor="cyan", length=50, width=10, sliderlength=10, resolution=0.01)
        self.water.pack()
        self.water.set(1.00)

        self.soil = Scale(self.main_right_frame, from_=0.01, to=1.00, orient=HORIZONTAL, bd=0, label="Terrestrial",
        background="white", troughcolor="saddle brown", length=50, width=10, sliderlength=10, resolution=0.01)
        self.soil.pack()
        self.soil.set(1.00)

        self.id_frame = Frame(self.main_left_frame, background="white")
        self.id_frame.pack(side=BOTTOM)

        # submit button
        self.submitbutton = Button(self.main_left_frame,text="Submit", background="black", foreground="white",
        width=6, padx="2m", pady="1m")
        self.submitbutton.pack(side=TOP)
        self.submitbutton.bind("<Button-1>", self.submitbuttonclick)
        self.submitbutton.bind("<Return>", self.submitbuttonclick)

        #Animal Matrix
        self.animal = [
        ('Odocoileous virginiana','White-tailed Deer',self.soil.get,0.99,0.01,0.99),
        ('Anguilla anguilla','American Eel',self.water.get,0.99,0.01,0.99),
        ('Trachemys scripta','Slider',lambda:self.soil.get()*self.water.get(),0.99,0.01,0.99)]

    def submitbuttonclick(self, event):
        self.id_frame.destroy()
        self.id_frame = Frame(self.main_left_frame, background="white")
        self.id_frame.pack(side=BOTTOM)

        A=self.animal

        #equation
        sigma = float(sum(reduce(mul,item[3:]) for item in A))
        B = [(item[0], "%.2f" % (item[2]()*reduce(mul, item[3:])/sigma)) for item in A]
        C = sorted(B, key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True)  

        Label(self.id_frame, text = C[0], background = "white").pack(side=TOP, anchor = W)
        Label(self.id_frame, text = C[1], background = "white").pack(side=TOP, anchor = W)
        Label(self.id_frame, text = C[2], background = "white").pack(side=TOP, anchor = W)

environment = Environment(root)       
root.mainloop()
```

Thanks to many contributed improvements, this code works!

Comment: See my update for an adequate, if somewhat awkward, approach.

Comment: You explain it very well, I've updated the code, and it looks like it should work, but the tuple-scale interaction is still giving me fits.  I tried declaring the scale entries as DoubleVar() variables, but no luck.  Who cares about awkward so long as the code is functional without being too verbose?

Comment: you aren't calling the function. You can't just multiply a function or method with a number. That's what I meant when I said "you have to break up the list comprehension a bit more to explicitly call `l[2]`" at the bottom of my post. You have to call it first. Something like `reduce(mul, [item[2]()] + item[3:])`.

Comment: whoops. didn't catch that.  thanks.  i'll play with it until i get it working, then update equation.

Comment: Never use `import *`, and *especially* don't use multiple `import *`.

Comment: No need for the first `reduce` in your posted solution; nor is there a need for the complicated nested parenthesis. You could just do `(item[2]() * reduce(mul, item[3:]) / sigma)`.

Comment: Dear Mike Graham -- why is this cluttered namespace any better than from Tkinter import*?  The module does not run any faster, I'm adding extra lines of code which I must now monitor and update when I add/delete various objects from the module, and why aren't N,S,E,W, etc all in one library!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing that I notice is that you define `A` to be an empty dictionary, and then overwrite that empty dictionary with `self.animal`, which is a list.

```
    A={}
    A=self.animal
```

So I'm not sure what you mean to do here. Then in your definition of `B` you slice it:

```
    B = [(A[0], "%.2f" % (reduce(mul,A[3:])*A[2][i]/sigma*A[2][i])) for A in A]
```

This doesn't square with *either* definition of `A`, because you can't slice a dict, but the starting index you chose is `3`, and the highest index in `self.animal` is `2`. Confusing! But looking more closely, it becomes clear that the problem is that you're reusing `A` as an indexing variable. You *really* shouldn't do that; it makes this code *incredibly* confusing.

It can also cause errors. Consider this code:

```
>>> a = range(10)
>>> [a for a in a]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> a
9
```

As you can see, the list comprehension causes `a` to refer to the last value in the sequence previously known as `a`. This doesn't happen in your code because you used a generator expression. But it's still hard to read and confusing. I *strongly* recommend doing this instead:

```
    sigma = float(sum(reduce(mul,item[3:]) for item in A))
    B = [(item[0], "%.2f" % (reduce(mul,item[3:])/sigma)) for item in A]
```

**Update**: OK, having made those changes, you still need to `get` the data from the scales. In your definition of `self.animal`, you use `self.soil.get()`, like so:

```
('Odocoileous virginiana','White-tailed Deer',self.soil.get(),0.99,0.01,0.99)
```

This puts the return value of `self.soil.get()` in a tuple. But then that value is fixed -- it won't ever change. You have to explicitly call `self.soil.get()` *every time* you want the updated value. Also, your list comprehensions don't ever access the value returned there. You slice them like so:

```
>>> l = ('Odocoileous virginiana','White-tailed Deer',
...      self.soil.get(), 0.99, 0.01, 0.99)
>>> l[3:]
(0.98999999999999999, 0.01, 0.98999999999999999)
```

Remember that indexing in lists and tuples starts with `0` -- so in the above tuple `l`, `l[0] == 'Odocoileous virginiana'`. So if you want everything but the first two things, you have to slice from index 2:

```
>>> l[2:]
(0.55000000000000004, 0.98999999999999999, 0.01, 0.98999999999999999)
```

But this still doesn't solve the root problem, which is that you have to call `self.soil.get()` to get the updated data. One way you could do that is simply by recreating `self.animal` every time the submit button is hit. That would be wasteful but it would work. A less wasteful (but still awkward) approach would be to save the function itself in the tuple, instead of the result of the function. You'd do that like so:

```
>>> l = ('Odocoileous virginiana','White-tailed Deer',
...      self.soil.get, 0.99, 0.01, 0.99)
```

Note the absence of `()` after `self.soil.get`. Now the tuple contains not a floating point value, but a function that returns a floating point value. You have to call it to get the value, but it returns the fully updated value every time. To combine functions, you can use `lambda`:

```
>>> l = ('Odocoileous virginiana','White-tailed Deer',
...      lambda: self.soil.get() * self.water.get(), 0.99, 0.01, 0.99)
```

Now you can call `l[2]` to get a value:

```
>>> l[2]()
0.30250000000000005
```

So to put it all together, you have to break up the list comprehension a bit more to explicitly call `l[2]`, but once you've done that, this should work. This is not an ideal setup, but I'm afraid I have to leave creating an improved architecture as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: A,B, anc C aren't dictionaries.  They're either list of lists or tuples--I admit I'm unsure which.  A is the original, B is the one generated by feeding the original into the list comprehension, and C is the one which orders B from highest to smallest based on the equation results.

Comment: `{}` is a dictionary. In your code, you assign `{}` to `A`, so for at least a moment, `A` _is_ a dictionary. Then it's a list. Then it's a tuple. Stop reusing variable names!

Comment: Thank you, I thought I had to declare an empty A={} object before filling it.  Deleted--works fine.

Comment: @Jeff, ah, I see, it's because it's a generator expression instead of a list comprehension. Well, you still shouldn't do it. And changing it to `item` doesn't cause an error for me.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake--I didn't change everything, just the last bit.  If it's better code, I will change to...item.  But this still leaves my original problem.

Comment: @Jeff, OK. What's your original problem? The problem that in your question is your second problem?

Comment: @Jeff, I have to take off, but looking at the error statement, it says `tuple index out of range`. The only thing being indexed here is `C`, and `C` should be a `list`, not a `tuple`. (And note that `sorted` returns a list, so the surrounding call to `list` isn't necessary.) The only explanation I can think of is that the code above is not the code actually throwing the error, and that you are accidentally overwriting `C` with a tuple somewhere in your real code.

Comment: My original problem is that I cannot modify the original equation to incorporate the scale widget variables referenced in column 2 of the A list of lists (abbreviate lol, so sick of typing that) so that when I slide the scales, multiplying the numerator and denominator in B lol by the column 2 value (scale.get) for any given row (animal) so the final product of the equation changes and reorders the animal probability values depending on where I set the scales before clicking 'Submit'.  The original equation does not take the scale data into account and I want to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

`A[2][i]/sigma*A[2][i]`
this bit is trying to index the float.
Should this be: `A[i]/sigma*A[i]` instead?

I did make the assumption that the values in A are all floats.

Comment: A[2][i] is referencing the second column of a given row (so perhaps it should be A[i][2]?) in the animal data list of lists which is either self.water.get(), self.soil,get(), or self.water.get()*self.soil.get().  These values should range from 0.01-1.00, depending on user selection.  So yes, they should be floats.  All the values in A[2:] are floats.  Hope this helps.  I think A[i] would include the text elements.

Answer (score 0):

The `for A in A` part seems a bit dodgy to me. It may be syntactically corrent, but it's ususally clearer to use different names for collections and elements in those collections.

Also `for isolates in A: i = A.index(isolates)` can be made much more effective by using `for i, isolates in enumerate(A)`, as `A.index(isolates)` can take a long time when A is big.

I know, not really an answer to your question, but I hope it's useful nonetheless.

To make it easier to debug (and to actually help you out), please rewrite this:

`[(A[0], "%.2f" % (reduce(mul,A[3:])*A[2][i]/sigma*A[2][i])) for A in A]`

into something a bit more readable. If you split it into something with multiple lines you can actually use a debugger, and easily see what variable is a 'float' and where it's being indexed.